# Totally geodesic surfaces of $\mathbb{S}^3$

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, surfaces, spherical-geometry

Let $\Sigma$ be a closed, connected and oriented surface embedded in $\mathbb{S}^3$. Denote by $\overline{K}$ and $K$ the sectional curvatures of $\mathbb{S}^3$ and $\Sigma$, respectively. Then, Gauss' equation gives that

$$K - \overline{K} = K - 1 = K_G,$$

where $K_G$ is the Gauss-Kronecker curvature of $\Sigma$. From Gauss-Bonnet theorem, it follows that

$$\int_{\Sigma} K_G \, \operatorname{dvol}_{\Sigma} = \int_{\Sigma} (K - 1) \, \operatorname{dvol}_{\Sigma} = 2 \pi \chi(\Sigma) - \operatorname{vol}(\Sigma). $$

Thus,

$$\operatorname{vol}(\Sigma) =  2 \pi \chi(\Sigma) - \int_{\Sigma} K_G \, \operatorname{dvol}_{\Sigma}.$$

In particular, if $\Sigma$ is totally geodesic, then $K_G \equiv 0$ and $\chi(\Sigma)$ must be positive. The only option is that $\chi(\Sigma) = 2$ holds, so that every totally geodesic surface of $\mathbb{S}^3$ must be a  $2$-sphere.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: From $\chi(\Sigma) > 0$, why can't you also conclude $\Sigma = \mathbb{R}P^2$?  (But it is true that $S^3$ with usual metric only has $S^2$ as totally geodesic surfaces.)

Comment: A much simpler argument is to note that a complete, connected, totally geodesic submanifold must be the union of all the geodesics that start tangent to the submanifold at one point. Since all geodesics in $\mathbb S^3$ are great circles, this shows that a totally geodesic surface must be the union of great circles that are tangent to a $2$-plane at one point, and hence an equatorial $2$-sphere.

Comment: @JackLee your argument has the advantage to work in the higher dimensional case.